# Keys disappearing when reading for the second time with `event, values = window. read() ` in PySimpleGUI

Tags: pysimplegui

When I use `event, values = window.read()` for the second time the keys `'IN1'` and `'IN2'` that I had set for `sg.InputText(key='IN1')` and `sg.FileBrowse(key='IN2', file_types= (('EXCEL FILES', '*.xlsx'),))` in `layout` no longer exist. In fact `values` becomes `None` . How can I set the keys such that they don't disappear? I don't want that `values` become `None` and I want the keys to remain. Thanks.

Comment: complete and short script preferred to show your case, not only just simple sentence about your issue.

Comment: My problem got solved.